# Configuring themes

Tags: gnome, themes, css

I've installed a gtk theme for my system, but for some reason the theme don't work well with context menus(I've already fixed that), the top bar and the dock. So, I want to change that orange line that appears on the bottom of the icons in the top bar and the orange dots in the dock.
What file should I edit to change these things? The gnome_shell.css seems to not work. (To change the context menus I've edited this file)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. If u want to do the same, edit the /usr/share/themes/Yaru-dark/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css or the normal yaru and search for the
/* Top Bar */ section. Look for the border and background colors and change for the colors you want.